# Why does an un-rendered element behave as if it has been rendered?

Tags: angularjs

I am slightly confused by this behaviour of Angular JS.

Angular.js' [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) will not render an element if the expression evaluates to false, if the documents are anything to go by. I have this piece of code in my html template:

```
<div ng-if="false">
  <img src="{{ imgPath }}" />
  <p>This block is not rendered</p>
</div>

// In the controller
$scope.imgPath = "/invalid/image/path";
```

When this template is rendered, I cannot, as expected, see the `img` element or the `p` element on developer tools:

[image: e]

However... when I look at the network tab, there is a request to fetch the image:

[image]

I thought that if the element is not rendered, it wouldn't function in any way or form since it doesn't exist... Why does the browser fetch the image in this case?

You can see the working code on [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1j9HCKay2d38irCs), you'll have to hit `F12` to watch the error on the console.

---

<sup>I know that using `ng-src= {{ }}` instead of `src={{ }}` would solve the issue of img src being fetched with unresolved expression before the data is bound, but, this question deals more with why `ng-if` isn't stopping the request in the first place</sup>

Comment: I believe the element is created, then `ng-if` is evaluated and the element is removed if the evaluation results in false. The element will actually exist for a brief moment which is what is causing the attempt to retrieve the image.

Comment: you need to understand that `ng-if` is nothing more than Angular directive, so to be processed element should be in DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes AngularJS a small amount of time to process your markup. So, intially when your page loads, the browser does it's thing trying to process the markup. It sees this:

```
<div ng-if="false">
  <img src="{{ imgPath }}" />
  <p>This block is not rendered</p>
</div>
```

But, so far, AngularJS has not been loaded, and the AngularJS directives have no meaning. The browser attempts to load an image located at the literal URL of : `{{ imgPath }}`, which the URL encoder will translate to `%7B%7B%20imgPath%20%7B%7B`, which will fail (obviously). Still, AngularJS has not been loaded.

Once AngularJS finally loads, it goes through the DOM and applies the `ngIf` directive and removes the node.

This is why you want to use `ngSrc`. This will prevent the image request, since the browser doesn't understand the `ng-src` directive and won't treat it like a `src` attribute.